End to end testing for a pipeline involving multiple nodes
Context:

I have a pipeline for getting the metrics from all the hosts system which are spread across different sites.
Each site has a gateway node (let's refer it as site gateway) and all the site gateway node are connected to another gateway node (let's refer it as master gateway).
Each host have Grafana agent running as a service which collects metrics and remote write it to the Prometheus deployed on site gateway node.
And Prometheus on site gateway node remote write metrics to Prometheus deployed on master gateway node.
Then at last the Prometheus on master gateway node write all the metrics to a long term metrics storage (Grafana Mimir).
Prometheus on site & master gateway is deployed on the local k8s cluster using a custom helm chart.

Pipeline flow:
Host 1(Grafana Agent) -> Site Gateway 1 (Prometheus) ---↓

Host 2(Grafana Agent) -> Site Gateway 2 (Prometheus) -> Master Gateway (Prometheus) -> Long term Storage (Grafana Mimir)
Question:
What are the ways on doing an end to end testing of this pipeline ??
